# В некоторых местах возникает ошибка "Конфликт размеров операндов". Как решить?

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер

```
__asm {
        mov    eax,     value
        // выделить 6 битов
        mov    r_m_a,   al
        and    r_m_a,   0x3f
        shr    eax,     6
        // выделить 3 бит     
        mov    reg1_a,  al//Конфликт размеров операндов
        and     reg1_a, 0x7
        shr    eax,     3
        // выделить  7 битов    
        mov    modl_a,  ax
        and    modl_a,  0x7f
        shr    eax,     7
        // выделить  2 битов
        mov    w_a, ax//Конфликт размеров операндов
        and    w_a, 0x3
        shr    eax,     2
        // выделить  2 битов
        mov    s_a, ax//Конфликт размеров операндов
        and    s_a, 0x3
        shr    eax,     2
        // выделить  5 битов     
        mov    kop_a,   al
        and    kop_a,   0xfff
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Для команды `mov` размер приемника и источника должны совпадать. В качестве источника вы используете регистры `al` (1 байт) и `ax` (два байта). Следовательно, именно такой размер должен быть у переменных-премников: `reg1_a` - 1 байт, `w_a`, `s_a` - по два байта